# How to localize built-in strings in a future-proof manner?

Tags: localization

I need to amend the labels for name and email fields in the comments form in my localized (Czech) Wordpress this way:

```
Emailová adresa    =>  Email
Webová stránka     =>  Web
```

What I did is that I've opened `wp-content\languages\cs_CZ.po` in poEdit, located the strings and compiled the new version of `cs_CZ.mo`. It worked well.

However, I imagine that when a new version of Wordpress comes out and the localization team releases new version of localization files, my changes will be overwritten, right?

So the question is, **how to change the localized strings in a future-proof way**?

I was thinking that maybe the comments mechanism provides some hooks to replace these two labels so I could create *.po and *.mo files in my theme directory but that doesn't seem to be generally applicable. What would be better would be to create a file like `cs_CZ-custom.mo` which would be able to override values already defined in the main language file but I'm not sure WordPress supports that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need the gettext filter.  lifted directly from the codex, here is an example:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_comment_field_names', 20, 3 );
/**
 * Change comment form default field names.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext
 */
function theme_change_comment_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( is_singular() ) {

        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'Name' :

                $translated_text = __( 'First Name', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;

            case 'Email' :

                $translated_text = __( 'Email Address', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;
        }

    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext#Change_the_Comment_Form